# UI Thread freezing up when adding Items to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, multithreading

in the following code I convert some images to binary format on a different thread, however my UI thread still freezes up, it should just display the items (ObservableCollection that holds the ByteImage is binded to) when each one is converted.

It seems like the images are being converted before the UI Thread has time to add each object to the ObservableCollection!

What is wrong? I noticed if I add the Sleep(4) it displays the images smoothly.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    // Generate List of images to upload
                    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sel.Name, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                        .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".jpeg") || s.EndsWith(".jpg") || s.EndsWith(".png"));
                    int b = 0;

                    if (files.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (string item in files)
                        {
                            // Generate new name
                            string oldname = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(item);
                            string newName = Common.Security.KeyGenerator.GetUniqueKey(32);
                            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                            {
                                Filenames.Add(
                                    new NFile
                                    {
                                        OldName = oldname,
                                        NewName = newName
                                    });
                            }));

                        }

                        // Manage each image
                        foreach (string item in files)
                        {
                            // Generate thumbnail byte array
                            var img = GenerateThumbnailBinary(item);

                            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                            {
                                UploadProgress = (int)Math.Round((double)(100 * b / files.Count()));
                                Thumbnails.Add(new ByteImage { Image = img });
                            }));
                            b++;

                            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(40);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Edit:
I'm now getting the following error, i'm assuming I just set the one line of code I want to add to the Task Thread? And then when it completes it executes the Dispatcher?

Error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'Dispatcher.Invoke(Action)'

Code:

```
// Manage each image
ByteImage img = new ByteImage();
foreach (string item in files)
{
    // Generate thumbnail byte array
    var task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        img.Image = GenerateThumbnailBinary(item);
    });
    task.ContinueWith((t) =>
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            Thumbnails.Add(img);
        });
    });

    UploadProgress = (int)Math.Round((double)(100 * b / files.Count()));
    b++;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider using the latest way of using the Task object by having the async await operators.

http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

You are actually dispatching immediately to UI any progress that is happening in your code. So technically I think it is still running synchronously.
Try to use continuewith for your dispatch calls like this:

```
var task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //simulate long operation
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
        });
        task.ContinueWith((t) =>
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                //do all UI operations here
            });
        });
```

I believe you can also save a lot of lines of code when you use IProgress object instead of using dispatcher to update your UI.

Comment: Is the class running the Dispatcher.Invoke method inheriting from a Window class? If not, you need to use Application.Current.Dispatcher to use the instance of Dispatcher in the current application. Calling Dispatcher.Invoke on a class that does not inherit from a UI class will make the compiler assume that you are trying to invoke on a "Dispatcher" type and not a Dispatcher object.

Comment: Ah that fixed that error as the class instance is run from a ViewModel class. So I have now replaced Dispatcher with Application.Current.Dispatcher however now my entire application hangs with no error message! Should I add the entire `for` loop in the `Task.Run`? Or am I doing it correctly?